# How rename a file in a zip archive with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, zip

All is in the title. Just to be complete, I just want to rename the file without modifying it.

Manu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there's an Ant task to manipulate the entries of a zip file in-place. Even the Java API doesn't support incrementally changing zip files, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4129445.

You could however just unzip the whole thing, rename the file you want, and then zip it back up:

```
<mkdir dir="tmp" />
<unzip src="src.zip" dest="tmp" />
<move file="tmp/src.txt" tofile="tmp/dest.txt" />
<zip destfile="dest.zip" basedir="tmp" />
```